# Are you missing an assembly reference on Unity after adding an open source code on the project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded an open source code folder and placed it inside my project's Script folder.

And this error pops up:

```
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlDevice.cs(26,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtDevice' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlFont.cs(25,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtFont' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlImage.cs(26,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtImage' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlLogger.cs(25,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtLogger' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlBehaviour.cs(151,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtCompiler' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlDevice.cs(50,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtFont' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlDevice.cs(67,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtImage' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlDevice.cs(83,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtRect' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlDevice.cs(83,52): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtColor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlFont.cs(72,29): error CS0115: `HTMLEngine.Unity3D.HtmlFont.LineSpacing' is marked as an override but no suitable property found to override
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlFont.cs(77,29): error CS0115: `HTMLEngine.Unity3D.HtmlFont.WhiteSize' is marked as an override but no suitable property found to override
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlFont.cs(84,25): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtSize' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlFont.cs(97,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtRect' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlFont.cs(97,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtColor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlImage.cs(68,29): error CS0115: `HTMLEngine.Unity3D.HtmlImage.Width' is marked as an override but no suitable property found to override
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlImage.cs(77,29): error CS0115: `HTMLEngine.Unity3D.HtmlImage.Height' is marked as an override but no suitable property found to override
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlImage.cs(88,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtRect' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlImage.cs(88,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtColor' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Assets/Scripts/HTMLEngine.Unity3D/HtmlLogger.cs(32,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtLogLevel' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

This is one of the cs file that have the error

```
namespace HTMLEngine.Unity3D
{
    public class HtmlDevice : HtDevice //This HtDevice turns red indicating an error
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

What do I need to do in order to fix these errors?

Comment: Probably alot of patience?  Seriously though, what open source project?  Show us your code. [mcve]; [ask]

Comment: @MickyD This is my first time having an open source code integrated to my project so I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Sadly neither will we if you don't help us help you by providing more info.  Wishing you well